# Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '<name_of_module>' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

this is part of my configuration file karma.conf.js:

```
    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '../',

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/app.js',
  'app/js/controllers/*.js',
  'app/js/services/*.js',
  'test/unit/*.js'
],
```

and this is my folders struct:

[image: folder's structure]

This is app.js file:

```js
/**
 * Created by Pietro on 30/12/15.
 */
'use strict';

var drfmApp = angular.module('drfmApp', [
    'ngRoute','drfmControllers','ngCookies'
]);


drfmApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController'
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
        }).
        when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
            controller: 'RegisterController',
        }).
        when('/dashboardESCO', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard_esco.html',
            controller: 'DashboardESCOControllers'
        }).
        when('/dashboardRetailer', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard_retailer.html',
            controller: 'DashboardRetailerControllers'
        }).
        when('/dashboardAggregator', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard_aggregator.html',
            controller: 'DashboardAggregatorControllers'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }]);

drfmApp.run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh
        $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
        if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; // jshint ignore:line
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page

            // $ è jQuery
            var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
            var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
            if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                console.log('Run Config: User not logge in or trying to access a restricted web page')
                $location.path('/login');
            }
        });
    }]);
```

I'm trying to run a simple unit test file like this (using Karma and Jasmine):

```js
'use strict';

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */
describe('Drfm controllers', function () {

    beforeEach(module('drfmControllers'));

    it('DUMMY TEST', function () {
        expect(3).toBe(3);
    });

});
```

where **drfmApp** is the name of the main module in app.js file

This is where drfmControllers is defined (in controllers.js):

```js
/**
 * Created by Pietro on 07/01/16.
 */
'use strict';

var drfmControllers = angular.module('drfmControllers', []);


drfmControllers.controller('DashboardESCOControllers', ['$scope',

    function($scope) {
        $scope.dashboard = "ESCO Dashboard";
    }

]);

drfmControllers.controller('DashboardRetailerControllers', ['$scope',

    function($scope){
        $scope.dashboard="Retailer Dashboard";}

]);

drfmControllers.controller('DashboardAggregatorControllers', ['$scope',

    function($scope){
        $scope.dashboard="Aggregator Dashboard";}

]);
```

But I always have this error:

```
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'drfmControllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=drfmControllers at /Users/Pietro/repos/drfmcockpit/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68
```

I read about the order of the *.js files in karma configuration file: but seems it is according to this rule [see "files" at the start of the question].

Thanks to everybody

---

**UPDATE SOLUTION:** changing the conf file with this:

```js
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/js/app.js',
      'app/js/controllers/controllers.js',
      'app/js/controllers/LoginController.js',
      'app/js/controllers/RegisterController.js',
      'test/unit/*.js'
    ],
```

It runs well. Seems something in files inspections. I don't know well..

Comment: Who u r calling controller? Post full test code.

Comment: Where is the `drfmControllers` module declared?

Comment: @david I haven't declared in the test file

Comment: @PietroPatFragnito where is it declared within your application, specifically in relation to drfmApp?

Comment: In controller.js. I've putted it in the question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set `basePath` in you configuration options. [By default](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html), it is equal to `''`. In it's turn, empty string as a `basePath` value, makes it relative to the configuration file directory. It is described [here](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html):

> If the basePath is a relative path, it gets resolved to the directory
>   where the configuration file is located

That means that either you should set `basePath` value to an absolute path, or you should change your files paths to relative, like:

```
files: [
  '../app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  '../app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  '../app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  '../app/js/app.js',
  '../app/js/controllers/*.js',
  '../app/js/services/*.js',
  'unit/*.js'
],
```

Comment: I had already set the "basePath". I'll put the value in the questions.

Comment: Is your controller right inside of `/app/js/controllers` directory? Or in another sub-directory like `/app/js/controllers/one_more_dir/controller.js' ?

Comment: All controllers are inside ../app/js/controllers

Comment: Provide more data please, it's hard to say so. Show the contents of `/app/js/controllers/ `directory and the code of your `/app/js/app.js`

Comment: I've added the info you need in the question. Tell me if you need something else. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, and where is `drfmControllers` defined? In `app/js/controllers/controllers.js`? Show it please.

Comment: yes in controller.js. I've putted it in the questions. Thanks so much

Comment: Ok, now try please to add `app/js/app.js`, after `'app/js/controllers/*.js',
  'app/js/services/*.js'` to the `files` option.

Comment: Ok, it's still hard to say. Can you please share on github your project so I could reproduce it on my local machine?

Comment: Eureka: see the question!